# Is this written in Kryptonian?

Tags: dc, superman, languages

I spotted this in my local book store and it piqued my curiosity.

[image: The Superman Files with unknown text]

It is part of the cover of The Superman Files,  ISBN: 9781449447151.

I can't find any where that explains the text on the cover. Is it a cypher for the English language,  or is it a recognised Kryptonian language? If not is there any record of what it is?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### No, it is not Kryptonian. The language is the Pre-Crisis 30th century shared galactic language of [Interlac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlac). It is a [direct cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher) made for comic readers of the [Legion of Superheroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Heroes).

- I recognized it from issues of the Legion of Superheroes which used to have coded messages in the stories or in the letter columns when I was a growing up.

> Interlac is the designated communication language of the 30th century United Planets in the DC Comics fictional universe. It is also the name of a similarly-used language in the TV series Babylon 5.

[image]

> - The first reference to Interlac as the "intergalactic universal language of the 30th century" was in Adventure Comics #379 published March, 1969.
> - It was also frequently referred to in the Super Friends comic book series (in which all of the Super Friends, including Wendy and Marvin, speak it) as a token explanation of how the Super Friends could understand the language of visiting and/or invading extraterrestrials.
> - The Interlac alphabet was codified years later by writer Paul Levitz and artist Keith Giffen in Legion of Super-Heroes (vol. 2) #312 (June 1984).

#### 'The Story of Kal-El' is the Interlac [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration).

Comment: To be pedantic, if you can convert from english to "Interlac" by replacing the symbols used to represent each letter, *it's still english*, just using a different alphabet.

Comment: Hence the term cypher in the second sentence. How much more precision do you require?

Comment: I think @FakeName is referring to the last sentence. Technically it should read "...the Interlac transliteration"

Comment: I was primarily responding to the sentence in the header: `The language is the Pre-Crisis 30th century shared galactic language of Interlac.`. A cipher is not a language.

Comment: To be clear, I'm aware it's a literary device, but it's still technically incorrect.

Answer (score 20):

If we take the bottom line as a correct substitution cypher for the English text above it, then the upper cypher text reads

> The Story of Kal-El

Vertical bars indicate a capital letter.

Comment: ...as confirmed by [Thaddeus' answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67897/19561).

Comment: Thaddeus's answer looks better, but this one actually translates the text.

Comment: Really? That isn't what was asked. And anyone who can knows what a simple cipher is can do the same. He didn't even ANSWER the QUESTION!

Answer (score 13):

I would say that no, that is not Kryptonian. As you can see on [*Omniglot.com*](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/kryptonian.php), the Kryptonian letters are totally different.

[image]

It must be a different alien language, since the letters differ quite a bit.

The site has a sample text in Kryptonian

[image]

in which we can see how much these two texts differ

The same Kryptonian alphabet can be seen on [*Superman Homepage*](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/comics/comics.php?topic=comics-kryptonian_alphabet)

Comment: Do you know what language it is?